# Hartshorne II Prop 6.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My weaknesses with commutative algebra are really slowing down my progress through Hartshorne.  I hope someone can help me understand some statements in the proof of the proposition below.

> Prop 6.8: Let $X$ be a complete nonsingular curve over $k$, let $Y$ be any curve over $k$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism.  Then either (1) $f(X)=$ a point, or (2) $f(X)=Y$.  In case (2), $K(X)$ is a finite extension field of $K(Y)$, $f$ is a finite morphism, and $Y$ is also complete.

I am confused about two statements in the proof, when we have case (2):  First, how do we know that $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$ finitely generated extension fields of $k$?  Second, why is it clear that $U=f^{-1}V$?

Also, Hartshorne then goes on to define the degree of any finite morphism $f:X\to Y$ of curves as the degree of the field extension $[K(X):K(Y)]$.  But how do we know that $K(X)$ contains $K(Y)$?

Comment: Are you trying to *learn* from scratch (or almost) algebraic geometry from Hartshorne? This may be a very bad idea: that book can be an excellent book but I think is a terrible text book for beginners, **even** with a hefty knowledge of commutative algebra.

Comment: @Timbuc Now you tell me!

Comment: Haha...sorry @slade. Next time.

Answer (score 5):

1) The fact that they are finitely generated extensions over $k$ is proved in Chapter I, Theorem 4.4. The point is that the function field of a variety $X$ is always determined by a dense open subset, so you can reduce to the affine case where it is pretty easy to see $K(X)$ is a finitely generated extension of $k$.

2) If $f:X\to Y$ is dominant, it induces an injection $K(Y)\subset K(X)$, and thus $K(X)$ is a finite extension of $K(Y)$.

3) To see that $U=f^{-1}(V)$, define $U$ as $f^{-1}(V)$ and note that it is integrally closed (by smoothness assumption).

Comment: I gave +1 but I still don't completely understand so I can't accept the answer right now.  For 1) it isn't clear to me that an integral domain which is a finitely generated $k$-algebra has it's field of fractions a finitely generated $k$-algebra.  I also still don't understand 3).

Comment: I should also note that for 2) it has to be proved that a finite morphism is dominant in this case, which is not trivial, I think.  I do have a proof with some help from another grad student.

Comment: @Seth It's not true that $K(X)$ is a finitely generated algebra!  It is, however, a finitely generated _field extension_.  In general, the function field of a curve has transcendence degree $1$, but only finite extensions are finitely generated _as algebras_.

Comment: @Seth With the right definitions, it should be very much immediate that the fraction field of a finitely generated algebra is finitely generated; use the same generators.

Comment: @Slade ohh I see, I guess that explains my confusion...

Comment: @Seth: to understad (3), we need to understand why smoothness implies integrally closed (or normal). Note that normality is a local property. On a smooth variety, all local rings are regular, and regular local rings are unique factorization domains (Auslander and Buchsbaum's theorem), hence integrally closed. Now any open inside a smooth variety is again smooth, hence, integrally closed. In our case, this means $f^{-1}(V)$ is integrally closed.

Comment: @adrido I don’t think 3) given by you is reasonable. Note that $Spec A$ is isomorphic to an open subset $U$ of $X$. Then he claims $U= f^{-1}(V)$. Not directly define $U=f^{-1}(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is written (pretty clearly, to my surprise) in the book: the given morphism is dominant and thus $\;K(Y)\subset K(X)\;$ , and since both fields are simple, finite **transcendental extensions** of $\;k\;$ of trans. degree one, $\;K(X)/K(Y)\;$is algebraic.

This is usually studied in a course in algebraic structures: fields extensions, Galois theory and etc.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but you didn't address any of my 3 questions.  The first question was, why $K(X)$ is a finite extension of $k$.  I apologize if this is trivial, trust me, I already feel stupid asking these questions here, but I'm genuinely stuck on some of this stuff and kind of overwhelmed.  Sometimes I can't tell when something is trivial and when it's a theorem I don't know about.

Comment: @Seth, perhaps you're confusing between "finite extension" and **finitely generated extension** , though in this context it is clearly the second one as both are transcendental extensions: they both are generated by one single element.

Comment: I misspoke, I meant finitely generated extension, I understand the difference.  However, I don't think that $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$ are a simple extensions of $k$, if they were, wouldn't they be isomorphic since they both have transcendence degree $1$?  My understanding is that because $X$ and $Y$ are of dimension $1$, their function fields have transcendence degree $1$ over $k$.  But I'm still not clear on why they are finitely generated extensions of $K$.  I guess it probably has something to do with $X$ and $Y$ being of finite type over $k$?